# Git format-patch output in a single file

Tags: git

How to direct the output of the command format-patch to a single file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

--stdout > filename

Comment: Be careful of this if you're using Powershell, [as it will cause your patch to be written in UCS-2 encoding which `git apply` doesn't understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675782/git-shell-in-windows-patchs-default-character-encoding-is-ucs-2-little-endian).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `git format-patch <branch> --output single.patch`