# How can I `git format-patch SHAx..SHAy` to output to a single patch file, not one per commit?

Tags: git

#### Conventional patch

`git format-patch OlderSHA..NewerSHA` normally creates one patch file per commit between `OlderSHA` and `NewerSHA`, exclusive of `OlderSHA` (it's the base for the changes) and inclusive of `NewerSHA`.

For instance, in this "real world" example, there are five commits between SHAs and so `git format-patch` makes five patch files.

```
git format-patch 3caf9c2..0aa9968
0001-About-as-far-as-you-get-adding-new-module-to-RCP-wit.patch
0002-Add-a-trivial-service.patch
0003-Rename-files-and-add-lazy-module-class.patch
0004-Add-WCS-shim-and-add-to-testRouteMap.patch
0005-Add-module-to-routing-to-enable-lazy-loading.patch
```

#### Problem statement

I would like to produce a **single file** representing all of the changes between `OlderSHA` and `NewerSHA` that could be applied in a single command. I'm not looking to preserve state between the two SHAs; I *only* want the final differences stored in the patch file.

```
git format-patch --single-file-option? 3caf9c2..0aa9968
EVERYTHING_BETWEEN_SHAs.patch
```

I've looked over the [docs on `format-patch` a bit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and if this is an option, I've missed it.

The problem is a little hard to google, as "single file", even "output single patch file" seem to converge on "I want patches that related to a single file" results instead.

Note that I also don't simply want [to concatenate five files into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290651/git-format-patch-output-in-a-single-file); I want the difference between the two commits in a single file with a single entry or section in the resulting file for each file's changes. (If `foo` changes to `bar` in commit 2 and back to `foo` in commit 5, I don't want it to appear in SuperPatch.patch)

Does this option exist?

Comment: Are you looking for `git diff`? `git diff 3caf9c2..0aa9968 > 3caf9c2..0aa9968.patch`

Comment: @phd Sheesh, argh... as it turns out, give or take yes. Want to answer that up? Looks like it's missing the email header stuff and, in my case, a note about which version of git was used at the bottom, but the files (when I test for a single commit) are otherwise the same. Why wouldn't `format-patch` support that, though? What's the difference in use case other than the implication you're going to email the patches?

Comment: It's not implication. It's its [documented purpose](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch): Prepare patches **for e-mail submission** (emphasize mine — *phd*).

Comment: @phd Okay, but other than the difference that its _explicit_ purpose is to create emails, how does the use case change? That is, why _wouldn't_ `format-patch` support the same sorts of conglomeration `diff` does?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most compact way to get this in general would be

```
git format-patch OlderSHA..$(git commit-tree -m - \
                           -p `git merge-base OlderSHA NewerSHA` NewerSHA^{tree})
```

with the merge-base needed in case OlderSHA isn't strictly an ancestor. If it is, you can lose it and do

```
git format-patch OlderSHA..$(git commit-tree -m - -p OlderSHA NewerSHA^{tree})
```

and if you want a nicer commit message in the patch you can use multiple `-m`'s or lose the `-m` and feed the full message in through commit-tree's stdin.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add some notes to @jthill answer.

"All of the changes between `OlderSHA` and `NewerSHA`" is ambiguous. Considering such a scenario,

```
git init foo
cd foo
touch a.txt
git add .
git commit -mroot
git branch new
echo hello > a.txt
git commit -am'hello'
git checkout new
echo world > a.txt
git commit -am'world'
git checkout master
```

The log graph would be like,

```
* d1f8ac1 (new) world
| * dd5329d (HEAD -> master) hello
|/  
* 8db55b4 root
```

`git format-pach master new` would create one patch for `d1f8ac1` only, whose diff is between `8db55b4` and `d1f8ac1`, as if generated by `git diff master...new` (three dots). It's different from the diff between `dd5329d` and `d1f8ac1`, as if generated by `git diff master..new` (two dots).

When `OlderSHA` is an ancestor of `NewerSHA`, the 2 diffs are the same. When `OlderSHA` is diverged from `NewerSHA`, as described in the above scenario, the 2 diffs are different.

There is also a special case, in which `OlderSHA` and `NewerSHA` are unrelated. They don't share any common ancestor. `git format-patch OlderSHA NewerSHA` generates patches for all commits reachable from both `OlderSHA` and `NewerSHA`. `git diff OlderSHA..NewerSHA` and `git diff OlderSHA...NewerSHA` generate the same diff.

When you need the `...` diff, use

```
git format-patch OlderSHA..$(git commit-tree -m - \
                       -p `git merge-base OlderSHA NewerSHA` NewerSHA^{tree})
```

When you need the `..` diff, use

```
git format-patch OlderSHA..$(git commit-tree -m - -p OlderSHA NewerSHA^{tree})
```

Here `git format-patch OlderSHA..$()` could also be `git format-patch -1 $()`. And for the special case, use the `..` diff way, or use the `...` diff way without `-p $(git merge-base OlderSHA NewerSHA)`

`git commit-tree` creates a commit, whose message log is specified by `-m`, whose parent is specified by `-p` and whose tree is specified by `NewerSHA^{tree}`. It's like to make a new commit based on `OlderSHA` or the merge-base of `OlderSHA` and `NewerSHA`, and the commit has the exactly same code with `NewerSHA`.